# Best way to understand javascript complex code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

What is the best way to understand javascript complex code, like I use to debugger for understand the java complex code.
So, there is any way for javascript like java?

Comment: Use plugins like *chrome developer tools* or *find bugs*

Comment: every modern browser has a developer tool for this purpose

Comment: I use comments to understand complex code… but if you want to use a debugger, there are debuggers for js as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use either IE/Chrome Developer Tools, press F12 on the browser and afterward put any breakpoint on javascript file.